# PDI MongoDB Input and Output steps

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pdi

I recently installed PDI 8.2 CE - doesn't look like it comes with the Mongo input and output steps...

I found it here https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-mongodb-plugin I unzipped that and put the entire folder in to the `../data-integration/plugins` directory and restarted PDI but still no mongo input/output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out and it appears that PDI is very picky when it comes to which versions of JDK/JRE your running on your machine regardless of what you have set as the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME.

Had to uninstall all of them, and then ensure that only OpenJDK 1.8 was installed.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to add any additional plugins because it's under big data section you will find both input and output for mongodb.

[image]

Comment: Not on 8.2 CE I installed the other day